# CSS layout (2 column layout, but if no sidebar main column must be 100% wide)

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

Column1 (left) is for content. Column2 (right/ sidebar) is for related info. say layout is 66%/34%. I need a way to make Column1 to stretch to 100% automatically if there is no sidebar content. Any idea's. I know it can be done. I just can't remember how.

```
+---------+---------+
| Content | sidebar |
+---------+---------+


+-------------------+
|Content/ no-sidebar|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this. Here are the two different HTML cases:

With sidebar:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">some content</div>
    <div id="main_content">main content</div>
</div>
```

Without sidebar:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main_content">main content</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS the conditionally changes the sizing of the `main_content` div:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 34%;
    float: right;
}

#main_content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#main_content:nth-child(2) {
    width: 66%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may set HTML like;

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">content
        <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS like;

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar, #content{
    height: 200px;

}
#sidebar{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#content{
    background: orange;
}
```

you may replace `px` with percentage. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/aBbtN/)*** is a Live Demo.

Comment: @user1147371 i know that you are a beginner. But here in stackoverflow, users must accept working answers. You may upvote my answer (by clicking up arrow) and accept my answer (by clicking tick icon)

Comment: block elements in content but not in sidebar mess this up. using display: inline-block helps with some of it but not all http://jsfiddle.net/Nkqr3/