# Two sidebars and flexbile center column CSS

Tags: html, css

Three column grid with fixed width sidebars and fluid center.

I am having a hard time with this. I have these properties:

```
#sidebar { width: 65px; padding: 0px; }
#content { width: 100%; }
```

Then it is all called in my template like this:

```
{% block left_sidebar %} Test {% endblock %}
{% block content %} Content {% endblock %}
{% block right_sidebar %} Test {% endblock %}
```

However, it puts the left sidebar on top of the "content" and the right sidebar below it. How can I overcome this?

If there is no content in the sidebar I want the middle content to fill up all availiable space. That is why I was trying to set it as 100% between the available space. So if there is no left column, I want the middle content to automatically fill up the left 2/3rds of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. I believe I have found the answer on stackoverflow herE:
I think I found the answer here:

[CSS layout (2 column layout, but if no sidebar main column must be 100% wide)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302935/css-layout-2-column-layout-but-if-no-sidebar-main-column-must-be-100-wide)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to float your divs left, and then make sure the total width is less than or equal to 100% of the container.

A rough idea:

```
#sidebar, #content {float: left;}
#sidebar { width: 10%; }
#content { width: 80%; }
```

Comment: This brings up a problem, because if there is no content in the sidebar I want the content to be the full width. That is why I was trying to set it as 100% between the available space.